# How to bind an interface to functions in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, list, random, pysimplegui

I have a next files:
https://github.com/Greenboyisyourdream/PasswordGenerator

How can i do to make the "generate" button execute the function on line 12 in the app.py

(The function on line 12 in the app.py):

```
elif button == "Generate!":
    screen.format()
    screen = str(*[random.choice(list(symbols)) for _ in range(lenght)])
    window.FindElement("output").Update(screen)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layout, you define key of `gui.InputText` as `'output'`, at the same time you also define key of `gui.Button` as same `'output'`.

### Using unique key for all elements in same window.

key of `gui.Button` here will be automatically changed to `'output0'`.

```py
layout = [
...
    [gui.InputText(screen, size=(40, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), background_color="white", text_color="black", key="output"),
     gui.Button(button_text="Generate!", size=(10, 1), button_color="red", key="output")]

]
```

The event generated when button clicked is the key of `gui.Button`, not button_text of element if option `key` or `k` specified.

The most easy solution to get right event `'Generated!'` is to remove option `key='output'` from `gui.Button`, or set option `key='Generated!'` in `gui.Button`.

```py
layout = [
...
    [gui.InputText(screen, size=(40, 1), font=("Times New Roman", 10), background_color="white", text_color="black", key="output"),
     gui.Button(button_text="Generate!", size=(10, 1), button_color="red")]

]
```